# Can anyone provide some more examples of picturesque speech?

Tags: creative-writing

There used to be a regular column entitled, “Toward More Picturesque Speech” in Reader's Digest, It was pretty heart warming, I used to adore it. Where can I find more of these?

Here are few examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just google "famous lines" and "Famous quotes" or read 19th century literature. Sorry, can't be much help.

Comment: @DWKraus FYI, OP flagged your comment with a response: "No they're not actually that easy to find..and by the way there is a difference between these and famous quotes"

Comment: For future reference, Manish, if you want to respond to a comment, you need to do it by clicking "Add a comment" underneath your question. Please don't use moderator flags to respond to comments, as the person you're replying to won't see your reply and it creates unnecessary work for us moderators. With that out of the way, would you be able to [edit] your question to clarify what your definition of "picturesque speech" is? It would also help if you transcribed the quotes instead of just including pictures of them, as your question can't currently be read by screen-readers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, taken literally, the OP is asking contributors to post their favorite descriptive sentences as answers. The OP is not asking a question whose answers can be assayed and evaluated as more or less accurate. As phrased, it seems a more appropriate subject for reddit or social media, and not a site dedicated to helping others grow their understanding

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because all answers will be equally valid ("list question"). These are off topic according to the help center: https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here's one from Alexandra Schwartz in the New Yorker, sep 19, 2022, p. 73

... bright sentences tossed up like juggling balls to be caught in dazzling rotation.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to satisfy your desire for beautifully worded descriptive sentences is to read more and find them for yourself. This way you could use the phrases you liked the most as elements of a search of the web.  If you used two or three such sentences and found one site that contained that text, then you'd likely find more sentences that you'd like to read.

Alternatively, if you found that no sites were really providing you with that kind of content, then you might consider it an opportunity to the share the sentences you loved with the world. That would lead to read even more so you could find and share more sentences.

### If you can find what you want on the web, look on it as an opportunity and not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one:

"The sky wearing a necklace of wild geese"

Citation: unknown author from Bing